# Resolving reverse urls in django

Tags: django, django-urls

Consider the following django site structure:

```
root/
- manage.py
- main/
-- __init__.py
-- settings.py
-- urls.py
- phase1/
-- __init__.py
-- urls.py
-- phase1/content/
--- __init__.py
--- models.py
--- views.py
```

i.e. 3 apps, main/, phase1/ and phase1/content/.

The root_url of the settings is main/url.py and
the relevant code of the modules are:

```
#main/urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^phase1/', include('phase1.urls')),)

#phase1/urls.py

url(r'^problem/(\d+)/$', content.views.view_problem, name='problem')

#phase1/content/models.py

class Problem(django.db.models.Model):
    ## stuff and fields
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return django.core.urlresolvers.reverse('content.views.view_problem',
                                                args=[str(self.id)])
```

it is clear that a request of url /phase1/problem/1/ asks for content.view.view_problem with the correct argument. However, the reverse function is not generating this path when it is used (on a template for instance).

If I add the prefix 'phase1.' on the first argument of reverse():

```
        return django.core.urlresolvers.reverse('phase1.content.views.view_problem',
                                                args=[str(self.id)])
```

it works. This is not what I want because phase1/ and content/ are supposed to be portable apps in the django sense, so "phase1" should not be inside the code of content/ app...

Maybe I'm missing something. Can someone give a proper explanation on why this is happening and a solution?

Comment: Check the settings in `manage.py`. If the directory related to `content` app is in manage.py, you would not have to include `phase1`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *name* of the url in the reverse.
ie,

```
return django.core.urlresolvers.reverse('problem',
                                        args=[str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Good, this is a possible solution. Reverse also supports the view namespace (as my last test showed), I'm also trying to understand why resolve isn't finding the phase1.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is far from portable. URL names collide between each others between apps.